# Thunar doesn't display thumbnails for most files

Tags: 14.04, xfce, gui, thunar, thumbnails

On Xubuntu 14.04 Thunar doesn't show thumbnails for most files. For example in my wallpapers folder only two `.png` files have thumbnails while the rest of them don't have thumbnails, similar for other extensions. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Two things to try: Firstly: Run this from Terminal: `sudo apt-get install tumbler tumbler-plugins-extra`  If this does not work: Close Thunar and then run: `mv ~/.config/Thunar ~/.config/Thunar.bak` and then reopen Thunar. If either of these work I will write up a formal answer...

Comment: Tumbler was already installed, tumbler-plugins-extra did not help. Moving the config files did tho, thanks for the help!

Comment: Great news :). I have created a formal 'answer' and it would be great if you could 'Accept' it by clicking on the checkbox (or 'tickbox') near the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible methods for fixing this issue, best tried in the order given here:

1. Ensure Tumbler is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install tumbler tumbler-plugins-extra
   ```
2. Generate a new config file by closing Thunar and then running:

   ```
   mv ~/.config/Thunar ~/.config/Thunar.bak
   ```

   and then reopening Thunar. This will generate a new, default configuration file.

This should rectify your issue...

Answer (score 1):

if install Nemo this fix pdf and others thumbnails  (also fix thumbnails in Thunar)
open Nemo go to Edit>>Preferences>>Preview
select:
Show Thumbnails:>> Always
Only for files smaller than:>> 100MB or 1GB
I tried this in Ubuntu Studio 18.10 XFCE